# Bot Channels Registration - Azure Bot Framework

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-authentication

When I tried to integrate my bot with Authentication at starting of the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp) I have found about 
 **Bot Channels Registration**

- Later I have searched for this in Azure Docs I haven't found about this **Can anyone please explain me**

  1. what is the use of this resource
  2. what is the process to start with this
  3. why is it useful, when we can directly register our app and get the client and secret id's
- is it possible to pass the direct endpoint / API here and can test it and integrate it into the channels from outside??

Answer (score 7):

A Bot in the Microsoft Bot Framework world basically consists of two things:

1. a registration within the Microsoft Bot Framework services (which includes an Azure App registration)
2. the "bot" itself, which is basically just a web-hosted resources that can receive and send json.

In the Azure resource listing, there is the option for a "Web Application Bot", which *combines* 1 & 2 above together - it includes the *registration* for the bot, as well as an Azure Web Application to host it behind the scenes.

If you want to host the bot yourself, then you only need "1" above, in which case you just choose the "Bot Channel Registration" option, and you supply a web address where your bot it hosted. It could still be in Azure of course, or somewhere else entirely (e.g. AWS, on premises, whatever). I've got a post on my blog that describes some of this behind the scenes, that might be of interest: https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work

Comment: To add on to Hilton's answer: a bot channels registration also hold all the channel connectors, which allows your bot to connect to channels such as Facebook, Teams, or simple webchat.

Comment: Yes, good point - I assume that's also why this option is called Bot "Channels" registration. It's one of the tab in this type of item in Azure.

Comment: You would be surprised how many people don't realize that. :D

Comment: Also, If you need to add authentication to a bot, we need to create oauth connection string in azure bot channel.(You wont get this option to create connection strings if you create Bot in legacy BotFramework/AppStudio). This OauthConn is required to establish connection between the bot and the secured resource like MSGraph.

Comment: Could somebody comment on how the process of doing a 'bot channels registration' has changed now that this option has been deprecated by Microsoft. Their documentation suggests that 'AzureBot' should be used regardless of where the bot is being hosted.  I'd like to connect my existing bot (botkit-based, hosted on AWS) to the Microsoft Bot Framework's web chat and I'm not sure what are the minimal requirements that need to be in place in the Azure cloud.